# Raspberry Pi HQ Camera Easier Focusing / Raspistill digital zoom

Tags: camera

Does anybody know of a way for raspistill to only show a small segment of the preview, but in fullscreen, so essentially it is very zoomed in (digitally), so that it is easier to focus when using a small screen? Currently it the pi camera is attached to a telescope which can be very fiddly to focus, so being able to zoom in to see when it is properly focused would massively improve the project.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that would not be possible with `raspistill`. You can read the docs [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md). I read it and didn't find anything that would be able to do what you specified. Something that might work is changing the `w` and `h` variables for the `--preview` parameter of the `raspistill` command to values that are larger than the resolution you are using. Though there's a good chance it won't work. If it doesn't, then reread the docs to make sure I'm not wrong with my answer. After that, your only option would be to edit the [source code](https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/blob/master/host_applications/linux/apps/raspicam/RaspiStill.c).

Comment: Thanks!
Thats worked perfectly, and its now much easier to focus on objects,

Comment: different but related: [Connect small touch-sensitive display to Pi 4 HDMI output to zoom-in on live PiCam camera output in order to carefully focus on some detail?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/127277/35753)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is Looking for a solution to solve exactly this problem with libcamera (bullseye): libcamera-hello --roi 0.3,0.25,0.1,0.1

x,y,zoom-x,zoom-y

Comment: You need to format the answer, code/command should be formatted as code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).